# How do I r/w access ValueTuple members by index?

Tags: c#, indexing, tuples

Following an example I found with google, I tried

What do I need to write into my cs file to make ITuple known there please? I googled for it, didn't find anything (maybe I am blind, but yet).

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class CMatrix
{
    public (CVector r, CVector u, CVector f, CVector t) m_data;

    public CVector this[int i]
    {
        get => ((ITuple) m_data)[i];
        set => ((ITuple) m_data)[i] = value;
    }
}
```

Result: "Class or name space name 'ITuple' not known".

My target framework is ".NET Framework 4.7.2".

Hint: The question is "how do I make it work", not "why doesn't my solution work". I only posted it to give an idea of what I want to achieve.

Comment: `ITuple` is in `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` namespace. You might be using an old runtime version which doesn't include `ITuple`. What's your target framework?

Comment: Even if you had access to `ITuple` - its indexer is readonly, so your setter won't work.

Comment: The question actually was "how do I make it work", not "why doesn't my solution work". My target frame work is ".NET Framework 4.7.2".

Comment: Where exactly did you find the example? Could you share a link?

Comment: Problem is you can't make it work, specifically the setter, because `ValueTuple` (the one which is mutable, `Tuple` is immutable) does not provide a way to set item by index. Well of course you can do the obvious thing (`if (i == 0) ... `)

Comment: Please clarify: your question title is different from the question you ask in the post body. Are you saying that .NET Framework 4.7.2 can't find the `ITuple` interface, or how to implement a setter for a Tuple??

Comment: So I would need to use an array then ... which means something like "CVector[] m_data = new CVector[4]; For (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) m_data[i] = new CVector ();"Is there a performant and elegant way to do it? Hint: I want vectors and matrices to be mutable.

Comment: @Razzupaltuff what are you trying to do? Why do you want to set value tuple items by index? What problem is going to be solved by this? The question describes what you think the solution would look like. As everyone already said this can't work. You're not only mixing up unrelated interfaces and classes, you're trying to use a `get`-only property to write. You still haven't explained what you actually want to do.

Comment: @Razzupaltuff this sounds like a case of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem X and assume Y is the solution (use a read-only interface to write). When that doesn't work you asked about Y, not the actual problem X.

Comment: I have explained what I want to: I want read/write access to ValueTuple members via an index (like in Python). I absolutely don't think that it plays a role why I want to do that. The body also clearly explains that my solution is just an attempt to solve the task. I am open for better, working solutions. This should be perfectly clear from my question already.

Comment: @Razzupaltuff the obvious solution to the problem is to write a `switch` that returns members based on the index. It will be a lot faster than casting, assuming that worked at all

Comment: @Razzupaltuff `I have explained what I want to: I want read/write access` and everyone already explained that's impossible using those types. This isn't Python. Neither the title nor the body are clear. Clear is `How can I set ValueTuple members by index?` Even that though is an attempted solution. Why set by index? If you want an array, why not use an array?

Comment: Have you tried using a `switch` ?

Comment: I thought about using a switch, but I love general solutions, so I will go for a completely different approach. I had an idea that couldn't work, alright then. Learnt something anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments mention, there is no way to use an index setter, and as far as I can see, the indexer always throws `IndexOutOfRangeException` for valuetuple on .net 4.8

The obvious solution would be to write your own indexer:

```
            get =>
                i switch
                {
                    0 => m_data.r,
                    1 => m_data.u,
                    //...
                    _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(i));
                };
```